# Why are women and children viewed as plunder in Deuteronomy 20:14?

Tags: hebrew, history, deuteronomy, hermeneutical-approaches, context

Deuteronomy 20 is about how Israel should wage war against nations that are far from them (excluding Canaan)
However, I am having trouble understanding why verse 14 views women and children as plunder, and not as human beings “As for the women, the children, the livestock and everything else in the city, you may take these as plunder for yourselves.”
Also, the verse says, “And you may use the plunder the Lord your God gives you from your enemies.” How is the plunder treated, badly, or good?
(Sorry if I didn’t ask this correctly, I am new to this site)

Comment: Perhaps there ought to be a tag for "cultural perspective". Even Biblical writers are influenced by the cultural norms of their own place and time.

Comment: That was the custom and ethics of the time.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 2):

The English word 'plunder' is used in the N.I.V. translation, but is not used at all, anywhere, in the Authorised Version. This is shown in Robert Young's *Analytical Concordance*, and in his literal translation of the Bible, he uses the word 'spoil' in Deuteronomy 20. The Hebrew word in the text is *'shalal'*. The Hebrew word for 'spoil' in the sense of taking something as spoil is *'baza'* but is not used anywhere in Deuteronomy. The Hebrew words for spoil, as in the sense of corrupting or destroying it, are *'shadad'* and *'shachath'*. Again, those words are never used in Deuteronomy.

However, even going along with the word 'plunder', ***there is no logic in assuming that women and children being spoken of as 'plunder' meant that they were not viewed as human beings***. Consider how the men killed in such battles (where they refused to sue for peace and therefore were to be killed) were living human beings who then became dead human beings. Being alive, or dead, did not change the fact of their humanity! Likewise with humans taken as 'spoil' or 'plunder' in a war; the only thing that changed regarding their humanity was that previously they were free human beings, but now they were captured human beings. **Their status in society had changed, but not their humanity.**

How those captured women and children were treated by the Israelites was detailed in other laws, and they were to be treated far more considerately than was the case with surrounding nations.